# Top 3 average scores from all of website users

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I am using the following query to calculate and display a users average score at some quizzes

```php
$query = 'SELECT AVG(answer) FROM quiz_answers WHERE id_user = '.$id_user.'';
$averagescore = mysql_query($query, $conn) or die(mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_array($averagescore);

echo number_format($row['AVG(answer)'],3);
```

This part works fine, but next to this individual info, I would also like to show the top 3 average scores of all our websites users, like a small hall of fame...

I have tried the following code:

```php
$queryall =  'SELECT * FROM quiz_answers WHERE id_user IN (SELECT id_user FROM quiz_answers GROUP BY id_user HAVING COUNT(id_user) > 1)'

$groupresultsbyuser = mysql_query($query, $conn) or die(mysql_error());
$rows = mysql_fetch_array($groupresultsbyuser);
$numberofrowsperuser = mysql_num_rows($groupresultsbyuser);
```

I am stuck here.. please help me to find a way of making it work.

Comment: What is the DB structure? How are the tables connected?

Comment: Do you only want the scores, or do you want the related user info as well?

Comment: @PatrickQ The related user info would be awesome, but I am hoping at least to make the best 3 scores to show...

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you want to display some user into (such as username) along with the high scores, you can pull the average scores by user, and then join against your user table (which, for the sake of argument, I'm calling `users` and assuming it has a `user_id` field)

```
SELECT u.*, scores.avgScore
FROM users u
    JOIN (
        SELECT id_user, AVG(answer) AS avgScore
        FROM quiz_answers
        GROUP BY id_user
        ORDER BY avgScore DESC LIMIT 3
    ) scores ON u.id_user = scores.id_user
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b5795/1)

Comment: Thank you for your answer but this doesnt work. The 'user' table and the 'quiz_answers' table have in common only the 'id_user' column. We basically need to select the rows from quiz_answers table, which have the same user_id, and create an average for each user. then just select the biggest 3 average scores and their correspondent usernames from the 'user' table...

Comment: As the first comment to your question suggested, you should show your table structure. And what exactly do you mean by "doesn't work"? If your id field on the `users` table is `id_user` instead of `user_id`, then simply change it in the query. Since I don't yet know what your exact table structures are, I had to make some assumptions/guesses.

Comment: @KlaussGekker I've added a demo to my answer to show it working.

Comment: the table 'quiz_answer' has the columns: id_quiz_answer,   id_quiz_category,  id_user,  date,  answer,                                                                           and the table 'user' has the columns:  id_user,   username, password, name,  email.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT id_user,AVG(answer)
FROM quiz_answers
GROUP BY id_user
ORDER BY AVG(answer) DESC
LIMIT 3
```